# Adding custom EditorTextField component to IDEA UI as a new editing tab

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How to add custom EditorTextField component to Intellij IDEA UI?

Need to  display it as a new text editing tab

Comment: [Refer to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/adding-gui-components-and-forms-to-the-palette.html).

Comment: I need to load a simple web page in a new editor tab by splitting that new tab. Is there any example I can refer ?????

Comment: [Markdown Support](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/markdown) plug-in does something like that.